# Spring JMS Connections: performance considerations

Tags: performance, spring, jms, spring-jms

I  have the need to send/receive messages towards/from different topics stored on a single JMS Server.

I would like to use `JmsTemplate` for sending and `MessageListenerContainer` for registering asyncronous listeners.

My configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">xxx</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">yyy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref ="jndiTemplate"/>
        <property name="jndiName" value="TopicConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="singleConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tosJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="singleConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="destinationResolver"/>
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

As far as I understood, the `singleConnectionFactory`, returning always the same connection instance, helps reducing the overhead of creating and closing
a connection each time a `jmsTemplate` needs (for example) to send/receive a message (as it would be when using a normal `ConnectionFactory`).

My first question is: if I create multiple `jmsTemplate`(s), can they all share a ref to a `singleConnectionFactory`? Or do they have to receive a distinct instance each (`singleConnectionFactory1`, `singleConnectionFactory2`, etc)?

Reading the API for `SingleConnectionFactory`, I found this:

> Note that Spring's message listener containers support the use of a shared `Connection` 
>   within each listener container instance. Using `SingleConnectionFactory` in combination only really makes sense for sharing a single JMS Connection across multiple listener containers.

This sound a bit cryptic to me. As far as I know, it is possible to register only 1 Listener per `MessageListenerContainer`, so I don't understand to what extent is a connection shared.

Suppose I want to register N Listeners: I will need to repeat N times something like this:

```
<bean 
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer"> 
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" /> 
    <property name="destinationName" value="destX" /> 
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listener1outOfN" /> 
</bean>
```

How many Connections are created in such case from connectionFactory? One for each ListenerContainer or just a pool of Connections? And what if I provide the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`-s with a ref to `singleConnectionFactory`?

What is the best approach (from the point of view of the performances, of course) in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if I create multiple jmsTemplate(s), can they all share a ref to a singleConnectionFactory?

Yes, this is fine.  The javadoc for `SingleConnectionFactory` says:

> According to the JMS Connection model, this is perfectly thread-safe (in contrast to e.g. JDBC).

JMS Connection objects are thread-safe, and can be used by multiple threads concurrenctly.  So there's no need to use multiple `SingleConnectionFactory` beans.

> As far as I know, it is possible to register only 1 Listener per `MessageListenerContainer`, so I don't understand to what extent is a connection shared.

This is true; however, each `MessageListenerContainer` can have multiple threads processing messages concurrently, all using the same `MessageListener` object.  The `MessageListenerContainer` will use a single, shared `Connection` for all of these threads (unless configured to do otherwise).

> Note that Spring's message listener containers support the use of a shared Connection within each listener container instance. Using `SingleConnectionFactory` in combination only really makes sense for sharing a single JMS Connection across multiple listener containers.

In other words, if all you have is a single `MessageListenerContainer`, then `SingleConnectionFactory` is unnecessary, since the single connection is managed internally to `MessageListenerContainer`. if you have multiple listener containers, and want them all to share a connection, then `SingleConnectionFactory` is required.  Also, if you want to share a connection between listening and sending, as you do, then `SingleConnectionFactory` is also necessary.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! If create a SimpleMessageListenerContainer with a ref to singleConnectionFactory I get the following exception:
"Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0' defined in class path resource xxx Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: setExceptionListener call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'exceptionListener' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead. Alternatively, ...."
Do you know if something is missing?